# android, how to get package name?

Tags: android, class, package

In my application I need to know the name of package name. I have no problem when I want to grab it in activities but i can't take it in other classes. Following code is working in activity but i don't know why it has problem in simple class.

```
String packageName = getPackageName();
```

In my class I tried to write this code:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
```

but compiler said `getApplicationContext()` method is undefined for this class.

How can I take package name within this class?

Comment: use BuildConfig.class.getPackage().toString(); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere/51479130#51479130

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simple, or another way is to pass Context into the helper class constructor:

```
MyClassConstructor(Context context){

        String packageName = context.getPackageName(); 
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Using instance of the class you can get package name by using `getClass().getPackage().getName()` to the instance

**Sample Code**

```
ClassA instanceOfClass = new ClassA();
String packageName = instanceOfClass.getClass().getPackage().getName();
System.out.println("Package Name = " + packageName);
```

Comment: But are you not creating an entire new instance of ClassA which is actually is going to perform some code on its own for no good reason?

Comment: I have a library in my project and I pass the context from my project to the lib.The lib invokes context.getPackageName() which gets the lib's package name not my project's package name.How could the lib get my project's package name through the project's context?

Answer (score 3):

If you use gradle build, use this: `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` to get the package name of the application.

Comment: please note that ApplicationID could be different than the actual package name used by your java classes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere/51479130#51479130

Answer (score 0):

getApplicationContext() is a  method of ContextWrapper ( super class of Activity).

If you want to use it in your classes you will have to pass a reference of a Context or its subclass  and then use it

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getPackageName()

```
class MyClass {
    Context mContext;

    public MyClass(Context ctx) [
        this.mContext = ctx;

    }

    String getPackageName() {
        mContext.getPackageName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

                        String packageName2 = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is make a class name constructor and pass the ApplicationContext in that constructor -

```
ClassConstructor(Context context){

        String packageName = context.getPackageName(); 
}
```

Comment: When posting answers, please consider whether your answer contributes something that has not already been said in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for this in Kotlin -

```
var pName = this.packageName
```

Answer (score -1):

MAUI:

```
// In class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
string? packageName = ApplicationContext.ApplicationInfo.PackageName;
```