# Android Studio set application name in flavour

Tags: android, build.gradle

[Building Your Project with Gradle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#workBuildVariants)
shows how to create flavours of your app (as below).

Anyone knows how to set the application name for each flavour as well?
e.g. for the demo version, show "my Demo" on the user's phone?

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs { ... }
    buildTypes { ... }
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            packageName "com.buildsystemexample.app.demo"
            versionName "1.0-demo"
        }
        full {
            packageName "com.buildsystemexample.app.full"
            versionName "1.0-full"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where the hell did you find the sample project? So frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

In that same link, they define how to create different activities for each flavor. Along with that, they define how to create separate strings.xml. Basically follow their example on creating different strings.xml and you can define the application name in the xml.

Comment: Hi Kalel. Thanks for the reply. I should have been more clear..Im looking for a way to do this in the gradle file without having to create xml files for each flavour .. the former being much cleaner and easy to maintain

Comment: Everywhere you want to assign the package name, you could try doing it from code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere. Otherwise, strings should be defined in the xml so you can localize the strings when needed.