# How to make invite a friend to all contacts in android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am trying to develop an application in which I want to use `refer/invite friend` option just like in whats-app through the phone contact list.

Like this:

[image: Screen shot]

I don't understand how to make it.

Comment: You can found the answer here ([Same question has Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111407/1302648))

Comment: Please check answer here([Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111407/1302648))

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android's [`ShareCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.html) for this:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
   .from(this)
   .setText("Check out a new app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<your-package>")
   .setType("text/plain")
   .setChooserTitle("Share with your friends")
   .startChooser();
```

Comment: It is  for  Share a application not  for a invite a friend option which is in last whatsapp,in which you can invite all friends to your contactlist.

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you post a screenshot from Whatsapp on what it looks like?

Comment: It means like there is invite a friend option visible to only those who doesn't have our app and who already have our  app this invite  button is not visible

Comment: when i open whatsapp > settings > contacts > invite a friend, they're using the `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`, like in my answer, if you're talking about a different feature please post a screenshot

Comment: ok, i see the screenshot in your question, and I need to agree with the "too broad" vote you received, this requires both server-side and client-side code, as well as interfaces with Facebook APIs, you need to try implementing this yourself, and limit your questions to specific issues that might arise

Comment: OK thank if you find any code or link related to this ,then please share it