# How to find the name of the package of the main activity in android?

Tags: android

My main activity starts with the following:

```
package com.example.alexander.bootintervals;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.alexander.libraryproject.MyLogger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ...
```

Now I am using some code from in other package, for example in `package com.example.alexander.libraryproject`. How can I get the name of the main app/package of where the main activity is defined? Is there a way to extract the string `com.example.alexander.bootintervals` from a code called which resides in `com.example.alexander.libraryproject`?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6589829/5470794

Comment: Almost, but I do not have a context in the code in the shared library.

Comment: check my answer i think it solves the problem of getting context of mainactivity

Comment: i suggest you to pass `getApplicationContext()` from an Activity to the library in an initialization method. Or else the lib won't be aware of the application neither during compile nor run time

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to get the full package name

```
String packageName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

Comment: Answer updated to use BuildConfig, which is context-less.

Comment: Not quite what I want. With that, I get the name of the library, but not of the main code calling the library. I get like `com.example.alexander.libraryproject` but what I want is `com.example.alexander.bootintervals` ...

Comment: I am not sure how to do that elegantly. Not sure if it is possible without `Context`. You could however, put a `public static String libraryName = "com.example.alexander.libraryproject"` in your class definition and call it that way. I know it isn't elegant but it would work...

Comment: What class do you mean? The one in 'LibraryProject'?

Comment: I mean for every class inside of `libraryproject` and `bootintervals` (in your example you showed the `MyLogger` class), put in the static String variable that can be called from anywhere.

Comment: But the 'MyLogger' class can be called from many DIFFERENT other modules/packages/MainActivities, with different names. So putting in something in a class in `libraryproject` does not help in any way. Maybe this was not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Try `MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName()` and ignore the last period and the class name that follows it.

Comment: No does not work. Neither `MainClass` is defined, nor the name `MainActivity`, because I am trying this code in the library. There is no main activity

Answer (score 0):

so simple:

```
   String full_package_name = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
```

if you dont have any context in you module do as below:
1- define an interface like below in your module (lets say X module):

```
public interface Provider{
  public String getPackageName();
}
```

2- in your App modules (lets say A and B) you need to send an implementation of this interface to the module X like below:

```
public class ProviderImpl implements Provider{
  @Override
  public String getPackageName()
  {
        return BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
  }
 }
```

then send the implementation to the module X some how:

```
ModuleX obj=new ModuleX(new ProviderImpl());
```

you can add whatever you want to this interface and make your Modules implement it.

then in your module X just call getPackageName() method of the implementation and get your packageName ;)

Comment: I have no main activity in the library. Not that simple!!

Comment: why dont you send the packagename to the library ? do you have any context in your module ? if you have there is another way to do so

Comment: Then I have to rewrite the library. I hoped that android would provide a way so a code knows actually what program it is running in. I mean, this can be done easily with code running in Linux,. Every Process has an ID and some information associated with it, but I guess Android is much much more complicated than that. Waybe what I want is just impossible...

Comment: if the module is going to be used by your own project you can define meta data in manifest and read in module (even pure java module) !!

Comment: are you talking about the manifest related to the package containing the 'MainActivity'?

Comment: no what android is doing is so logical. you can access MainActivity from your library but it makes circular dependency. the best way is passing a context if its android module or passing the packagename as string to library.

Comment: there is alot you can do but you must tell me the exact case you have. are both application and module yours ? or you have a module that is going to be used by others ?

Comment: Ok, then I have to pass the module name or something to the library. I will probably define an interface in the main code to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125340/discussion-between-alex-and-newbie-androider).

Comment: look i updated the answer this is the neatest way to do this but you can send an string variable instead of implementations too but thats not the best practice ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125348/discussion-between-the-androider-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

you can add static function `getInstance()` in `MainActivity` that return the context of it and you can use it to get it's context and calling function that gives you package name as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static MainActivity instance;

    public MainActivity () {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
         return instance;
    }
```

***and use it as following:***

```
MainActivity.getInstance.getPackageName();
```

Comment: The library function does not know of any `MainActivity`. It cannot work...

Comment: are you have more MainActivity in libraryProject  and another one in bootintervals ?

Comment: No, I do not have a main activity in 'libraryProject'. It contains only classes I am using in different projects. Only 'bootinterval' contains a MainActivity

Comment: The library function does not know of any MainActivity..what do you mean of that, where is your problem exactly after trying this solution

Comment: The problem is, that AndroidStudio does not know a class named `MainActivity`. The term `MainActivity` is marked in red letters in the editor of AndroidStudio in the code, that is in `LibraryProject`. The project `LibraryProject` does not contain a class `MainActivity`.

Comment: Ok , try to import package `com.example.alexander.bootintervals` in your project class to see `MainActivity`