# Unable to getPackageName() using MediaPlayer in fragment

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

While using fragment I'm trying to get audio file from raw folder like this:

`mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(audioFile, "raw", getPackageName()));`

I'm getting `Cannot resolve method 'getPackageName()'` error. How to solve this?

Comment: try getActivity().getPackageName();

Comment: @BIW error: `Cannot resolve method 'create(com.example.myproject.FirstFragment, int)'`

Comment: okay try mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(audioFile, "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));

Comment: @BIW now `Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'`

Comment: hmm okay weird, let me have a little look around

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere

Comment: String pName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).packageName and put pName in the parameters of the create method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by writing this code:

```
String path = "android.resource://"+"com.example.myproject"+"/raw/"+audioFile;
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getActivity(), Uri.parse(path));
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```