# How to get main applicationId inside code in the library module?

Tags: android, gradle

I have library module where I'd like to starService through Intent(String). When I set:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".REFRESH_DATA");
```

My BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID is a library package. I need a variable in my code which will be populated with the main app package.

Comment: Call `getPackageName()` on a `Context`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I assume there is no solution without `Context`? Because of that I have to pass `Context` every time I use param / action in Intents: `private static final String ACTION_LOCAL_DATA_CHANGED = ".LOCAL_DATA_CHANGED";     public static String getActionLocalDataChanged(Context context) {
        return context.getPackageName() + ACTION_LOCAL_DATA_CHANGED;
    }`

Comment: You can have the app pass in the package name itself. Your question indicates that you want to call `startService()`, which means that you already have a `Context`.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `context.getPackageName()`.

> Note: The application ID used to be directly tied to your code's package name, so some Android APIs use the term "package name" in their method names and parameter names. This is actually your application ID. For example, the `Context.getPackageName()` method returns your application ID. There's never a need to share your code's true package name outside your app code.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module#set-application-id)

Comment: `packageName` is not the same as `applicationId` and can vary if you use different `applicationId`s for different build flavors.

Comment: according to the link witch pasted on my answer, context.getPackageName() will return applicationId.

Comment: I think this doesn't apply to multi variant/flavor