# Reading variable from gradle file to library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries

I'm writing a library. This library sends data by communicating with the cloud in the background. But the library has multiple users. And I have an ID that is used to identify each application (user). The library needs this ID to communicate.

My main question starts here. When the user adds my library to the dependencies, I want to add the ID value to a variable that he will add to the Gradle file and reach the value from the library to ensure communication. (Just like the OneSignal AppID in Gradle)

I'm not asking about getting application package ID..

But I don't know how to add this and how to access this variable from within the library, I need your help.

I've done relevant research, but people haven't shared information about it, so I couldn't make an experiment. I also searched before opening the title, and examined the relevant headings from opening the title, but I could not reach a conclusion.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I want to access the AppID defined on the Gradle in the library to enable data communication.

With this method, users simply add my library to the dependencies, and the Gradle can be used to quickly define a variable.

Thank you for reading the title and for your support.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that should be put in a Gradle build file. Rather, make it a configurable value for the library, whether it's through a file or a `Configurator` class.

Comment: I was inspired by a company like Onesignal to define it like this in Gradle, of course I am open to other solutions. But it is in the foreground for me to keep the user setup in the easiest way.

Comment: Other people's solutions aren't always the best ones. If you want to configure your library through Gradle and it makes sense to do so, you should probably write a plugin for it. There's not really a decent way to read Gradle parameters at runtime.

Comment: Maybe AppID should use the app package name? It's much more easier than situation I think.

Comment: That's an easy way of doing it, but it'd be prone to overlapping package names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get main applicationId inside code in the library module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769004/how-to-get-main-applicationid-inside-code-in-the-library-module)

Comment: @MartinZeitler Did you read the question? I didn't ask about getting application package id...

Comment: this is the same string, unless using flavors - and you probably won't get any better answer. besides the `build.gradle` you've posted is irrelevant and does not demonstrate the least attempt (it's just another one of these "I want to" questions). did you ever read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @MartinZeitler The build gradle I published is represented as an empty build gradle that will depend on the library. My goal is to learn how to define the variable into it already. How do you restrict me from asking questions based on your guess? I asked this question to get a better answer. I have already stated that I have read other relevant questions and relevant answers if you read my question. I've read the how to ask questions in detail, and I fill  in  my question in the template given by StackOverflow. Please give an answer if you have any information or do not engage here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `manifestPlaceholders` property to your library `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [my_app_id: "\${my_app_id}"] // <- important backslash!!!
    }
}
```

2. Add meta data with the placeholder to your AndroidManifest.xml library

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.mylibrary">
    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="my_app_id" android:value="${my_app_id}" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

*Backslash escapes $ and android merger will insert raw text `${my_app_id}` inside the AndroidManifest.xml. From now on every app that uses this library will have to define manifestPlaceholder with the key `my_app_id` or there will be manifest merge error.*

3. You can access `my_app_id` from your library code with the following lines:

```
public class MyLibrary {
    public static String init( Context context ) {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo( context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA );
            return (String)ai.metaData.get( "my_app_id" );
        } catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
            //TODO: handle exception
        }
...
}
```

When your app include the library it will also merge AndroidManifest.xml with the placeholder to fill. You have to define `my_app_id` inside build.gradle of your app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [my_app_id: "686adbd9-c3c4-458d-ab8c-d549f5d71de3"]
    }
```

*Manifest merger will now overwrite placeholder with the value from the app and library will see changed value in the application package*

**You can clone sample project with this idea from:
https://github.com/mdawid/ManifestPlaceholderLib**