# Packagename of Installed apps

Tags: android, package-name

I want to work on an `app` similar to [Package Name Viewer 2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csdroid.pkg&hl=en) that could load the `packagenames` of all the installed apps in the `device`. Actually I have searched a lot about it even discussed with my seniors and even tried to contact with the owner of [Package Name Viewer 2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csdroid.pkg&hl=en)but got no answer. I am not asking to write the whole code just give a favor that how can i achieve this.

**In short: I want to add the code in `onCreate()` that whenever app starts it should load all the `packagenames` of installed apps.**

Related Question: [How to get package name from anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) to retrieve [ApplicationInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo) of all apps.

```
 public static List<App> getAllAppInstalled(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<App> apps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        String applicationName = ((packageInfo != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo) : "Unknown").toString();
        if (packageInfo.enabled) {
            apps.add(new App(applicationName, packageInfo.packageName));
        }
    }

    return apps;
}
```

App class should look like:

```
public class App {
private String appName;
private String appPackage;

public App(String appName, String appPackage) {
    this.appName = appName;
    this.appPackage = appPackage;
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Did this help to retrieve all package names?