# How can I get the package name of the android in any file with in a static method

Tags: android, android-context

I am trying to get the package name of the app using the below code in my adapter java file. But I am getting nullpointer exception.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
```

Code:

```
private static boolean appsPackageName() {
        PackageInfo pInfo;
        try {
            pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }

        if (pInfo.packageName.equals("com.app.sample")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return  false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get package name from anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589797/how-to-get-package-name-from-anywhere)

Comment: No, BuidConfig.ApplicationId not returning the package name of the app

Comment: are you **really sure** the `context` is non-null before invoking the static method? If you can, consider refactoring the method signature to `appsPackageName(Context context)` so that you can be absolutely sure you pass in a non-null context from wherever you're calling this method.

Comment: Yes I have context as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get package name by using this simple code in your activity

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
```

if you are not in activity then you can use

```
context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
```

In Fragment you can use this

```
requireActivity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
```

Comment: I am not using activity or fragment. If I use context it crashing the app.

Comment: Then you have not defined context. Can you share more code. I mean context=?

Comment: private Context mContext;